# How to create generic function for multiple components?

Tags: jquery, css, html, animation, core-animation

I have post button on click of it a fish appears and it moves randomly in a container.

When I again click on the post button I want another fish to appear and move randomly over my container. In the below code the next fish which was clicked 2nd time follows the same path of the first fish.

Can you please help me creating a generic animating function so on click of each time of post button? Each fish moves randomly in random paths without following the prev one.

Note: If you have any doubts please execute the code and click on post button 2 to 3 times.

```
 <section class="main-content" id="container">
<input type="button" value="Post" class="post-button" /> 
<img src="Assets/Arrow.png" class="right-arrow" alt="arrow" id="rightarrow" /> 
    </section>

   $('.post-button').on('click',function(e){
$('#rightarrow').after('<div class="fishhatch" ></div>');//new fish created
animatenewfish();//animation to move the fish randomly in my container
    });


 /*Animating the fish*/  
     function animatenewfish() {
var Fishv1 = $(".fishhatch"),
theContainer = $("#container"),
maxLeft = theContainer.width() - Fishv1.width()-100,
maxTop = theContainer.height() - Fishv1.height()-100,
leftPos = Math.floor(Math.random() * maxLeft),
topPos = Math.floor(Math.random() * maxTop)+100,
imgRight = "Assets/R1gif.gif",
imgLeft = "Assets/FIsh1.gif";

if (Fishv1.position().left < leftPos) {
    Fishv1.css("background-image",'url("' + imgRight + '")');
}
else {
    Fishv1.css("background-image",'url("' + imgLeft + '")');
}

Fishv1.animate({
    "left": leftPos,
    "top": topPos
}, 18000, animatenewfish);
     }
```

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/BPLQa/2/

Comment: This was a deliberate copy-and-paste of one of the OP's questions. Since it is closed, voting to delete.